# how to use object as series for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I'm really new to javascript and Highcharts so really sorry if this is a dumb question.

I have an object (called val) like this:

Object {month: Array[12], corporate: Array[12], family: Array[12], party: Array[12]}

Each array includes sales value over time for corporate/family/party.

I want to create a line chart in Highcharts with 3 lines (corporate, family, party) over time.

Below is my code:

```
$(function () {
$('#expandable-3').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: val
});
```

});

The chart is showing blank.

Could someone please help me on how to get this work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you view the options on the highcharts demo you can see how the series is specified. [Highcharts basic line demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic)

You could change val to something like this:

```js
var val = [
  {
    name: 'corporate',
    data: [1,2,3]
  },
  {
    name: 'family',
    data: [1,2,3]
  },
  {
    name: 'party',
    data: [1,2,3]
  }
];
```

To convert your data use something like:

```js
Object.keys(val).map(function (key) { 
  return { 
    name: key, 
    data: val[key] 
  }; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured my val was not set up properly. I just don't know how to do it. Could you please tell me how to convert my val to the right format?